# /bin/sh bad syntax in for loop

Tags: bash, loops

I'm trying to run this script in my synology wit /bin/sh, it's all I have.

And while the script is working fine in normal /bin/bash environment, Synology is showing this error:

```
/volume2/myCustomPath/rotatingSnapshots.sh: line 22: syntax error: bad for loop variable
```

This is the code, the line which Synology is complaining about is the first one:

```
for (( i=$BIGGEST_NUMBER; i>=1; i-- ))
do
   ## Some code here
done
```

Any ideas? I can't find what is wrong.

Comment: Remove the `$`. Try `for (( i=BIGGEST_NUMBER; i>=1; i-- ))`

Answer (score 0):

`/bin/sh` refers to the POSIX shell. You're trying to use bash syntax in your script sp you should ideally be using the bash shell. This should work for you-

(Incidentally, you also don't need the `$` in the loop).

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=BIGGEST_NUMBER; i>=1; i-- ))
do
   ## Some code here
done
```

Comment: Only on  some systems is `/bin/sh` implemented by `dash`, on some it is in fact implemented by `bash`; however, your larger point stands that if you want to use `bash` syntax you should use `bash` as your shell.  `sh` is  generally fairly POSIX compliant, and that `for` loop syntax is not part of POSIX

Comment: `/bin/sh` is, *by definition*, the POSIX shell.